# Emulate C inline semantics from C++

Tags: c++, c, inline

C and C++ mean different things by inline.

In this specific context, my goal state is a single object file defining N functions with extern "C" style linkage, and also a C++ header defining those same functions such that they can be inlined by users of that header.

There are users that cannot include that header because they're other languages that do not parse C++ headers. I wish for those to be functional even though they can't benefit from the early inlining.

In C, you do this with an inline function in a header and stating that function without the inline keyword in a source file, thus emitting the symbol in that specific source file.

In C++ this is not a thing as far as I know, you're supposed to include the header everywhere and have the linker deduplicate.

This feels like a problem other people will have run into. Before I do something ugly with the preprocessor, does C++ have a proper solution to this goal?

Comment: It may not be what you want but you can probably use clever conditional compilation controlled by the presence of `__cplusplus` (conditionally make `inline` definitions visible for C++ in the header, or the non-inline ones in a separate file for C). It is probably desirable to avoid redundancy and have a single implementation file with the definitions which is conditionally modified and included by the header depending on the language.

Comment: But you *do* want to use C++ features *within* the implementation, don't you? So implementation within the header is no option?

Comment: Add this in one of your .cpp files: `namespace detail { const auto myFunctionAddress = myFunction; }` The compiler will emit code for `myFunction` and you can link against it from other languages.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Interesting!

Answer (score 1):

With link-time optimizations (`-flto`) your compiler is able to inline functions across compilation units. Here's an example: https://godbolt.org/z/Wrqaqo1YM

So, you should be able to define them in CPP files and rest assured that your compiler takes care of inlining when necessary.

Comment: I have no concrete experience with that ... could it be too costly at compile time for large code bases?

Comment: @Peter I don't know if it increases much compile time honestly. It's been good in my experience and I think this is the best way to do it, because it's less error-prone (no possible ODR violations) and it even helps with debug build times, because you can remove the `-flto` and you don't have to rebuild everything just because you changed an inline getter somewhere in a header file.